# How would one update the view after init, but without using didInsertElement()?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I initialize a jQuery plugin slider in the function `didInsertElement`.

Unfortunately, I'm also updating a computed property on the page, and when the computed property is updated, the sliders are re-initialized because the `didInsertElement` function fires again.

Is there a function that will fire once *after* the html elements are printed in the view, so I can initialize my sliders, but not every time the page is changed, or an element is deleted or removed?

---

Edit:

I tried:

```
didInsertElement: function () {
    Ember.run.once(this, 'initSliders');
}
```

but, unfortunately, it still runs every time the computed property is updated.

---

Edit 2:

I tried wrapping the initialization in a boolean:

```
didInsertElement: function () {
    if(!this.get('slidersInitialized')) {
        Ember.run.once(this, 'initSliders');
        this.set('slidersInitialized', true);
    }
}
```

but that didn't work, either.  Since the view is rerendered, the sliders need to be initialized again.

Would wrapping the portion of the view that's being updated with the computed property prevent the *entire* view from being rerendered, preventing the sliders' elements from being destroyed and recreated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer to my issue.

All I needed to do, was wrap the value in its own view to prevent the rest of the view from being rerendered:

Original template:

```
...
<div class="append field">
    {{input class="narrow input" id="widthInput"  placeholder="Any / Unknown" value=width}}
    <span class="adjoined">{{view.widthInFt}}</span>
</div>
...
```

New template:

```
...
<div class="append field">
    {{input class="narrow input" id="widthInput"  placeholder="Any / Unknown" value=width}}
    {{view view.widthInFtView}}
</div>
...

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="widthInFt">
    {{view.widthInFt}}
</script>
```

After I created my template, I created the view class as a child inside my other view that I did not want to be rerendered:

```
widthInFtView: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "widthInFt",
    tagName: "span",
    classNames: ["adjoined"],

    widthInFt: function() {
        var ft = parseInt(this.get('parentView.widthSliderValue') / 12, 10);
        var inches = parseInt(this.get('parentView.widthSliderValue') % 12, 10);
        return ft + " ft. " + inches + " in.";
    }.property('parentView.widthSliderValue')
}),
```